# Does the limit exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, definition

I had a question about the definition of a limit. I know for a limit to exist the right hand limit must equal the left hand limit but what if the graph of a specific function has the domain from [0,5] and if you wanted to find the limit at x=5 you know the left hand limit exists but the right hand doesn't.

So in this situation does the limit exist or not since only the right-hand limit exists?

Comment: The left hand limit exist only

Comment: No, the limit does exist.

Comment: If the right hand limit is not defined, then THE limit does not exist, unless the domain can be extended beyond 5 and both right hand and left hand limit exist and are equal

Comment: Well, only left limit exists (since to the right the function is not defined), but that's ok: the limit coincides with the left limit.

Comment: "The limit coincides with the left limit, so the limit exists? Ehhh...??

Comment: @imranfat Many calculus texts tend to be more restrictive, but there is no universal definition. Informally, it is often permitted that at least one "one-sided" limit exist so that "the" limit exists. (considering where the function is defined)

Comment: Yes, I am referring to calculus texts indeed, because that's where limits are introduced. I also think that it is better that the OP would have a particular example. Then it makes more sense to talk about different cases. In case of, for example $y=\sqrt{x}$ you cannot talk about THE limit $x$ goes to zero exists, because the left hand side cannot possibly exist. That's a standard example and thus I agree with Marty's answer. Now when the restricted domain of [0,5] is imposed  say on $y=x^2$ for x→0, then we can be less restrictive...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only discuss limits
in neighborhoods
where the function is defined.

If the function is
only defined in $[0, 5]$,
then it makes no sense
to talk about a
right-hand limit at $5$.
Therefore,
when you talk about
a limit at $5$,
you can only mean
left-hand limit.

Comment: That a better way of wording it +1

Comment: In this case, the left-hand limit and the limit are the same thing though.

Comment: So does the Limit exist overall?

Comment: @Asker123 I think it is better to come up with particular examples...

Comment: For my question above, after reading all of the comments and the answers I think the limit does exist assuming that the limit can exist only on a given domain with boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the usual definition of the limit of a function of a real variable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement).

If $D$ is *any* subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function, and $c \in D$ (more generally $c$ can be a limit point of $D$), then we can talk about whether $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists.

This stuff about left and right hand limits needing to coincide for the limit to exist only applies when $c \in D$ and $D$ contains an open interval about $c$.

For example, suppose $D = [0,5]$, and $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the function $f(x) = x^2$.  Then $\lim\limits_{x \to 5} f(x)$ exists and is equal to $25$, because for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $x \in D$ and $|x - 5| < \delta$, then $|x^2 - 25| < \epsilon$.

So in this case, $\lim\limits_{x \to 5^-} f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 5} f(x)$ exist, but it makes no sense to talk about $\lim\limits_{x \to 5^+} f(x)$.